# Error:CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I am getting this error on my android studio. I was add `git.exe` path but still this error come.

```
Error:CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Event Log

```
Gradle sync failed: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (110ms)
```

> I set Git Path : C:\Users\Riyaz\Desktop\PortableGit\cmd\git.exe

Basically i don't know the reason why this error come. I was just check solution on google to solved this problem and i fount this error reason is GIT but i already try to follow solution nothing work.

[Download Log File](http://megsta.com/idea.txt)

Comment: Probably incorrect punctuation `"git,exe"`. Should be `"git.exe"`

Comment: Mistake while type link on Here otherwise its on point.

Comment: try copy paste the `C:\Users\Riyaz\Desktop\PortableGit\cmd\git.exe` in command line. If git works, then probably you need to configure the Android Studio

Comment: Go to Preferences -> Version Control -> Git. Check your git path there.

Comment: I already add same link on android studio also test file while click text button, so file is pointing, But error still here.

Comment: I don't think your problem related to git. On the Event Log, click the Show Log for details.

Comment: i added a log file please check this log file.

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "E:\YTbooster\java.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\Riyaz\.gradle\daemon\4.1"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`. Why your `java.exe` is inside YTbooster? Did your computer got infected with malware? And also check for `C:\Users\Riyaz\.gradle\daemon\4.1`

Comment: no there is no malware i just install new window and in this location C:\Users\Riyaz\.gradle\daemon\4.1 there is 2 files.

Comment: If you're fresh installing Windows and Android Studio, the `java.exe` should be inside the Android Studio folder because Android Studio is shipped with java. Try to rename the folder `4.1` to regenerate the folder. And check for your java path.

Comment: try  running `E:\YTbooster\java.exe`. Though I don't think it's a genuine java executable.

Comment: E:\YTbooster\java.exe there is no java file. Why android studio point this location there is no java file available.

Comment: Alrights, you found the problem :D. You then need to set the correct path for the java. go to File > Project Structure > SDK Location. Then select `use Embedded JDK`

Comment: already set to recommended